# Calculation of the gravity model in R and Stata software: why are coefficients the same but standard errors different?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stata

We performed calculation of the gravity model in R and Stata software.

For calculations we used the standard package `glmm` in R (with parameter `family = quasipoisson`), and `ppml` in Stata.

Call the calculation procedure in R:

```
summary(glmm<-glm(formula=exports ~ ln_GDPimporter + ln_GDPexporter + 
    ln_GDPimppc + ln_GDPexppc + ln_Distance + ln_Tariff + ln_ExchangeRate +
    Contig + Comlang + Colony_CIS + EAEU_CIS + EU_European_Union, 
    family=quasipoisson(link="log"),data=data_pua))
```

The results in R were:

[image: The results of the calculations in R]

On the same data, we performed calculations in Stata, using `ppml` procedure:

```
ppml exports ln_gdpimporter ln_gdpexporter ln_gdpimppc ln_gdpexppc ln_distance ln_tariff ln_exchangerate contig comlang colony_cis eaeu_cis eu_european_union
```

The results of the calculations in Stata were following:

[image: The results of the calculations in Stata]

As you can see, model coefficients (second column in the results table) are the same at least until the 4th mark decimal place.

However, other results (from the third column in the table of results) are not the same.

- Could you explain differences in the results?
- In particular, why are coefficients the same (the first result table columns), but standard errors are not?

Answer (score 7):

I note that the Stata coefficient table mentioned "Robust Std. Err.", while `glmm` is probably not using robust errors. That would account for SE differences.

Also, `ppml` seems to actually drop "non-significant" regressors, and R's `quasipoisson` family allows for over dispersion in a way that's different from, say, negative binomial regression, which is perhaps different from `ppml`.

I noticed that you asked in a couple of places about what R package would yield equivalent results to `ppml` for (economics) gravity models, and got no answers. I'm sorry to see that and wish I could give a more-informed recommendation. *It appears that what you need is a Poisson regression with robust standard errors, that handles zero values. I'm not sure what R packages support that.* (Not sure if `ppml` handles over dispersion or not.)

Bayesian regression packages such as `rstanarm` might handle heteroscedasticity more robustly, but I am not sure. I'd tend to use something like a `student_t` family for that, but you have to use `poisson` so I'm not sure of the answer there. You might try the negative binomial family (`neg_binomial_2` in `rstanarm`'s `stan_glm`), which also handles over-dispersion and may be more robust than `quasipoisson`.

See also: [When to use robust standard errors in Poisson regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41723/when-to-use-robust-standard-errors-in-poisson-regression)

Comment: If one is willing to use `rstanarm` but the required functionality isn't there, one could make the leap to just coding up the model in `rstan`.

Comment: PPML is still consistent when there is under- or over-dispersion. You can read more at the [Log of Gravity page](http://personal.lse.ac.uk/tenreyro/LGW.html).

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо! А нельзя ли продублировать ответ по-русски :)

Comment: @salnsg: Sorry, Dmitry, unfortunately I only know two Russian words. You could try translate.google.com, though I doubt it will handle the technical parts properly.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Wayne's excellent answer, `ppml` uses a robust (to heteroskedasticity) variance-covariance matrix and also a finite sample adjustment to that matrix to reduce bias.

These are very similar to what `sandwich()` from the package of the same name computes in R. The only difference is how the finite-sample adjustment is done. In the `sandwich(...)` function, no finite-sample adjustment is done at all by default, i.e., the sandwich is divided by 1/n where n is the number of observations. Alternatively, `sandwich(..., adjust = TRUE)` can be used which divides by 1/(n - k) where k is the number of regressors. Stata, however, divides by 1/(n - 1).

Here's how you can get R to match Stata by using a custom sandwich variance with an adjustment factor of 1/(n-1):

```
. clear

. set more off

. capture ssc install rsource

. use http://personal.lse.ac.uk/tenreyro/mock, clear

. saveold ~/Desktop/mock, version(12) replace
(saving in Stata 12 format, which can be read by Stata 11 or 12)
file ~/Desktop/mock.dta saved

. rsource, terminator(XXX) rpath("/usr/local/bin/R") roptions("--vanilla")
Assumed R program path: "/usr/local/bin/R"

Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: 'zoo'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Beginning of R output

R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10) -- "Very Secure Dishes"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

>   library("foreign")
>   library("sandwich")
>   library("lmtest")
>   mock<-read.dta("~/Desktop/mock.dta")
>   glmm<-glm(formula=y ~ x + w, family=quasipoisson(link="log"),data=mock)
> 
>   sandwich1 <- function(object, ...) sandwich(object) * nobs(object) / (nobs(object) - 1)
>   coeftest(glmm,vcov=sandwich1)

z test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 0.516969   0.098062  5.2718 1.351e-07 ***
x           0.125657   0.101591  1.2369    0.2161    
w           0.013410   0.710752  0.0189    0.9849    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

> 
End of R output

. 
. ppml y x w

note: checking the existence of the estimates

Number of regressors excluded to ensure that the estimates exist: 0
Number of observations excluded: 0

note: starting ppml estimation
note: y has noninteger values

Iteration 1:   deviance =  139.7855
Iteration 2:   deviance =  137.7284
Iteration 3:   deviance =  137.7222
Iteration 4:   deviance =  137.7222

Number of parameters: 3
Number of observations: 100
Pseudo log-likelihood: -173.89764
R-squared: .01628639
Option strict is: off
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   .1256565   .1015913     1.24   0.216    -.0734588    .3247718
           w |   .0134101   .7107518     0.02   0.985    -1.379638    1.406458
       _cons |   .5169689   .0980624     5.27   0.000     .3247702    .7091676
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the Stata/R code that generates the output above. I am using `rsource` to run R from Stata (and you will need to tweak the `rpath()` below to match your setup), but that is not really necessary: you can just run the `rsource` part from R.

```
clear
set more off
capture ssc install rsource

use http://personal.lse.ac.uk/tenreyro/mock, clear
saveold ~/Desktop/mock, version(12) replace

rsource, terminator(XXX) rpath("/usr/local/bin/R") roptions("--vanilla")
  library("foreign")
  library("sandwich")
  library("lmtest")
  mock<-read.dta("~/Desktop/mock.dta")
  glmm<-glm(formula=y ~ x + w, family=quasipoisson(link="log"),data=mock)

  sandwich1 <- function(object, ...) sandwich(object) * nobs(object) / (nobs(object) - 1)
  coeftest(glmm,vcov=sandwich1)  
XXX 

ppml y x w
```

Comment: @salnsg Пожалуйста, напишите если я могу что-то уточнить. К сожалению, я не знаю как все это описать на родном языке.